# exportasfixedformat no paper size

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I'm trying to use the `exportasfixedformat` in C# excel file export to a pdf file. But the excel file is too big when converted to a pdf file (column and rows) paper size. Is there a way to eliminate the paper size when exporting an excel file to pdf file?.

```
ws.UsedRange.Font.Size = 5;
ws.UsedRange.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow";

ws.UsedRange.Columns.ColumnWidth = 20;

Range RS;
RS = ws.get_Range("A:A", Type.Missing);
RS.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 30;

ws.PageSetup.Zoom =false;
ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;

ws.PageSetup.Orientation = 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
ws.PageSetup.PaperSize = 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperLegal;
ws.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0.5;
ws.PageSetup.RightMargin = 0.5;
ws.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0.5;
ws.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0.5;

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, Filename,
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityMinimum, 
    true, false, 1, ws.UsedRange.Count, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

But the output of this code produces letters overlapping each other which make them unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set FitToPagesTall or FitToPagesWide before calling the export function.

```
ws.PageSetup.Orientation = 
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;

// Zoom property must be false, otherwise the "FitToPages" properties 
// are ignored.
ws.PageSetup.Zoom = false;

// these set the number of pages tall or wide the worksheet will be 
// scaled to when printed.
ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1;
ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to save Excel as A4 size PDF, it may be necessary to change the excel settings according to the excel version.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey Keyxls = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\16.0\\Excel\\Options", true);
if (Keyxls != null)
{
    Keyxls.SetValue("A4Letter", "0", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    Keyxls.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition;
It is necessary to select Microsoft Print to PDF as the default printer.
Then the desired page (e.g. A4 or A3) size is set.

To set the default printer setup,

- Open the Devices and Printers dialog.
- Select Microsoft Print to PDF
- Right-click, and set Printing preferences, including Advanced, appropriately.
- Right-click and set Printing properties appropriately.

Next time you use PDF printing, the new defaults should work.